# problem accesing viewmodel properties from OnPropertyChanged event in custom control

Tags: c#, xamarin, events, xamarin.forms, custom-controls

I have some custom control from github which and every time something changes from this control I need to send a socket tcp message with some conditions on a viewmodel. I have the OnPropertyChanged in the code behind of the view which calls a sendMessage function in the viewModel.

The message is sent correctly but the conditions (properties of the viewmodel) are not taken from the actual values. For example: I have an IsEnabled bool property which is turned true, but read false in the sendMessage function when accessing via the OnPropertyChanged thread.

I can only image that the OnPropertyChanged event is fired from a different thread that cant access to main thread´s values, so i have tried the following:

```
  Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => 
  MainViewModel.getInstance().Joystick.sendMsg(JoystickControl.Distance, 
  JoystickControl.Angle));
```

This would be the code for the custom control, which is working fine, in xaml:

```
       <CustomControls:JoystickControl x:Name="JoystickControl" 
        Grid.Row="4" BackgroundColor="#ececec"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center" 
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                    Margin="0,10" BindingContext="{Binding 
            Joystick}" PropertyChanged="JoystickControl_PropertyChanged" 
                      IsEnabled="{Binding IsJoystickEnabled}">
         </CustomControls:JoystickControl>
```

This would be my complete code behind:

```
      private void JoystickControl_PropertyChanged(object sender, 
       System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
         {
        if (Application.Current.MainPage != null)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => 

    MainViewModel.getInstance().Joystick.sendMsg(JoystickControl.Distance, 
    JoystickControl.Angle));
              }
           }
```

This would be my property that I need to evaluate:

```
    public bool IsTeachFlag { get; set; }
```

I have also tried with this one:

```
    private bool isTeaching;
    public bool IsTeaching
    {
        get { return this.isTeaching; }
        set { SetValue(ref this.isTeaching, value); }
    }
```

The one above calls a SetValue method to invoke on property change

I have the sendMessage function:

```
   public  async void sendMsg(double distance, double angle)
          {
            Response = new Response();
        if (IsTeachFlag) { 
     MainViewModel.getInstance().SelectedDevice.Message = "TEACHING,Distance=" + distance.ToString() + "&Angle=" + angle.ToString(); }
        else { MainViewModel.getInstance().SelectedDevice.Message = "DATA,Distance=" + distance.ToString() + "&Angle=" + angle.ToString(); }

            Response.Message = tcpService.sendMessage(MainViewModel.getInstance().SelectedDevice);

            if (Response.Message.Contains("FormatException"))
            {
                Response.IsSuccess = false;
                 await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(Languages.Error, Languages.FormatValidation, Languages.Accept);
                return;

            }
            else if (Response.Message.Contains("ArgumentNullException") ||
               this.Response.Message.Contains("SocketException") || this.Response.Message.Contains("Exception"))
            {
                Response.IsSuccess = false;
                 await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(Languages.Error, this.Response.Message, Languages.Accept);
                return;

            }

            else if (Response.Message.Contains("OK"))
            {
                Response.IsSuccess = true;

            }

            if (Response.IsSuccess)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(Languages.Error, Languages.tcpMessageError, Languages.Accept);
            }


    }
```

I have also tried without async and the results are the same: I never get the IsTeachFlag value when it is true. I have tried with other properties as well.

What I basically need is to fire an event when the joystick is moved. I have tried GestureRecognizers (swipe) and some other stuff and this is what got it working the best.

What can i do to access the viewmodel properties to get the actual value on the main thread?

Comment: Where exactly the `IsTeachFlag` property gets updated?

Comment: You have bound the `IsEnabled` property in XAML. Have you implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your viewmodel?

Comment: @Vahid Yes. I have implemented a BaseViewModel Which has all the INotifyPropertChanged and its events, which is inherited by all the ViewModels. The  IsEnabled is an ICommand used to enable the joystick. That part is no problem.

The IsTeachFlag property never gets updated. This I did it because I intended to use originally the IsTeaching property and did not work. So IsTeachFlag is there only to see if it worked that way, which it didn´t.

Comment: Have you resolved your problem?

Comment: @JessieZhang Not really, I had to come up with a different archutecture for my system. Up to now i haven´t found how to do that properly. Any help would be much appreciated!